# Is sole purpose of some moderators is to do autocracy / dictatorship

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers, moderators

Moderator deleted all my answers and comments. I have pre-written answers to some of basic questions on my blog. 
I refered my blog for some basic answers.

### Some users find that useful also as you can see.

[Error while installing PMD in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398629/error-while-installing-pmd-in-eclipse/33422798#33422798)

From one's perspective it also looks like self promotion. 
But it is also helping someone. Now moderator deleted all my useful/unuseful answers/comments and repudiation from 57 to 1.

Comment: This is what usually happens when you post the same answer multiple times. Did you see this comment? [*"Stack Exchange doesn't tolerate blatant self-promotion. You've already done this with several of your answers. They'll just get deleted eventually."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27154587/pmd-installtion-in-eclipse#comment54641039_33422894) Btw, what's the actual question?

Comment: This comment came late. I admit that at some places that goes wrong. but some ppl down voted my very old response also. Some of them were useful as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398629/error-while-installing-pmd-in-eclipse/33422798#33422798    At this time it is like doing good and bad are same. Some ppl took it like taking revenge and they just got started. Not even seen that some things were useful.

Comment: Moderators respond to flags from the community. In your case, moderators responded to six flags on seven posts like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006820/is-the-pmd-eclipse-plugin-open-source/33422601#33422601 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956906/eclipse-configuration-with-pmd/33422547#33422547 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956258/inheritance-in-core-java/33306258#33306258 that all said little more than "Some helpful concept with example about Inheritance. View Here" with a link to your ad-supported website. The votes came in along with those flags from the community.

Comment: If you have questions about the reasoning behind a moderator's actions, bring them up for discussion on meta. Remember to be constructive and polite; moderators have the best interest of the site in mind, but they may occasionally make mistakes or have to deal with controversial issues on which not everyone agrees. http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: @Just_A_Man The user was last active on here in 2017, so I doubt they would write more. But did you see the outcome of this question? The user got help, edited their answers and had them undeleted by a moderator. That's not quite what I'd call "dictatorship".

Comment: @Just_A_Man It's in the comments on the answer. They got their answers restored. So all went well, asking for help is one of the resons why meta exists.

Comment: @Just_A_Man It came across as accusatory, which is often not well received. Volunteers don't like being called "dictators". Other users who ask politely and express the wish to improve their posts have a much better experience.

Comment: @Just_A_Man The kids are grown up, yes, but the kids had to deal with insults like these (warning, not safe for work): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1288408 So, being called "dictator" is rather mild in comparison. Still, that it what moderation volunteers here have to deal with. Wanting to help is met with "f off, I just want my question answered". So, no, the kids don't want to be called "king". It would be enough not to be called names.

Answer (score 18):

> Is sole purpose of some moderators is to do autocracy / dictatorship

### No

Moderators are users of our sites who volunteer their time to be [human exception handlers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and step in when the community cannot handle something.

In this case, several of your answers were flagged as spam by other members of the community because they appear to be promoting your website.  The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) is very clear about self-promotion and many of your answers only seem to exist to drive traffic to another website.  Feel free to edit your answers and remove the links to your site. Once you do that, then you can flag them for review asking for a moderator to undelete them.

Comment: umm.. why the [user's reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1289948/kunal-saxena?tab=reputation) is 1 on SO? There is no suspension notice...

Comment: @ShadowWizard because that's their net rep? :p

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is no suspension. Due to the spam flags they got the penalty for posting spam.

Comment: Huh! Forgot it's not showing in the reputation tab. So confusing...

Comment: several of my answers which are not related to any kind of promotion were also voted down, spammed and deleted. My account  is suspended @ShadowWizard happy ?

Comment: @kunalsaxena you are not suspended. And no, I am not happy even if you would be - just sad you don't understand the site's rules and why you has been punished by downvotes and deleting your posts.

Comment: @bluefeet I have corrected most of the answers. Can someone review and correct from you side as well ?

Comment: @kunalsaxena I've undeleted several of the answers that you updated.